# TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class

Tags: django, metaclass

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers, ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: why you need **serializers, ModelSerializer** both

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```